# Remote Powershell not working but test-wsman does

Tags: powershell, powershell-v3.0, remote-access, powershell-v4.0

I need to script some routine task to execute remotly from a serverA to many hosts but a couple of them fail to execute the script.

If i execute this:

```
$cred = Get-Credential myUser
Invoke-Command -ComputerName serverB -ScriptBlock{gci d:\} -Credential $cred
```

or this:

```
Test-WSMan -ComputerName ServerB -Credential $cred -Authentication Negotiate
```

I get the following error

> [SeverB] Connecting to remote server ServerB failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process
>   the request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090322 occurred while using Negotiate authentication: An unknown
>   security error occurred.
>    Possible causes are:
>     -The user name or password specified are invalid.
>     -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
>     -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
>     -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
>     -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
>    After checking for the above issues, try the following:
>     -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
>     -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or
>   use HTTPS transport.
>    Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
>      -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more
>   information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (serverB:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : -2144108387,PSSessionStateBroken

But when i used test-wsman alone:

```
Test-WSMan -ComputerName ServerB

wsmid : 
http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/identity/1/wsmanidentity.xsd
ProtocolVersion : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd
ProductVendor   : Microsoft Corporation
ProductVersion  : OS: 0.0.0 SP: 0.0 Stack: 3.0
```

I dont know where the problem could be. I had already tried using **enable-psremote**, **winrm qc**, checking firewall settings and user priviledge

Comment: do you mean enable-psremoting?

Comment: also, have you tried adding serverb to trustedhosts (temporarily, as a test)?

Comment: @mike shepard yes, i ll edit my question. And also yes i have already donde that

Comment: How about using IP address instead of server name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. There is a known issue between Kerberos Autentication, Remote Powershell and Intregation Service (the server is running that app). 
Info can be found [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/0a728f24-ee8e-496e-834d-eced9eeb969d/ps-remoting-with-kerberos-authenticated-sites?forum=winserverpowershell) and [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/bb623545-f68f-41a0-8f71-e6f4b9da7a3b/winrm-20-kerberos-issue-with-kerberossecured-web-site-on-same-server?forum=windowsserver2008r2management)

I have to create an A record DNS to the server (serverB_alias) and set the HTTP spn for this server to the account specifyng the port that wsman tries to connect (5985).

```
setspn -s http/serverB domain\user
setspn -s http/serverB.domain domain\user
setspn -s http/serverB_alias:5985 domain\user
setspn -s http/serverB_alias.domain:5985 domain\user
```

Finally, i add to server A trusted host list the alias DNS using:

```
$curValue = (get-item wsman:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts).value
set-item wsman:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -value "$curValue, serverB_alias"
```

Answer (score 1):

seems like an issue with exsting spn mapping issue , In powershell you can delete spn account and retry.

```
setspn -D HTTP/SERVERNAME <domain account>
setspn -D HTTP/SERVERNAME.DOMAINAME.COM <domain account>
```

if the issue persists, you can check with using ip address (IPv4) instead of server name to bypass Kerberos error.

Source
https://serverfault.com/questions/580411/windows-server-manager-kerberos-error-0x80090322

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a4c5c787-ea65-4150-8d16-2a19c569a589/enterpssession-winrm-cannot-process-the-request-kerberos-authentication-error-0x80090322?forum=winserverpowershell

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue on VMWare and fixed it by following these steps

> I removed both ServerA and ServerB from Active Directory Users and
> Computer.
>
> I then changed Network-ID of both ServerA and ServerB from Domain to
> Workgroup
>
> I then restarted both ServerA and ServerB and moved them back to
> Domain
>
> I then run `Enable-PSRemoting -force` on both ServerA and ServerB if
> `WinRM service` is not running.