# Powershell Remote PSSession Failing - Domain Administrator Account - Error 0x80090322

Tags: windows, kerberos, winrm

I am troubleshooting an issue I have with a PRTG sensor not collecting Windows Update information from one of our servers. It is using WinRM and a remote PowerShell command to do that.

Server 1 - Issue Server

Server 2 - Working Server

When I try to use `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Server1` or `winrs -r:Server1 dir` to test the connection I keep getting the following errors:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> winrs -r:Server1 dir


Winrs error:WinRM cannot process the request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090322 occurred while using Kerberos authentication: An unknown security error occurred.
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Server1
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server Server1 failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The
following error with errorcode 0x80090322 occurred while using Kerberos authentication: An unknown security error occurred.
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Server1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Server1:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

If I run the command on any of our other servers the connection is successful, this is the only one giving me trouble.

If I run the command `Enter-PSSession` with the `-Credential` switch with my user account I get the same error, but if I run the command and specify the local administrator account of the server it will connect. Other servers work fine.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Server1 -Credential Server1\administrator
[Server1]: PS C:\Users\Administrator\Documents> exit

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Server1 -credential domain\myuser
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server Server1 failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The
following error with errorcode 0x80090322 occurred while using Negotiate authentication: An unknown security error occurred.
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Server1 -credential alpenaw2k.local\kemp ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Server1:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Server2
[Server2]: PS C:\Users\user\Documents> exit
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

If I run `New-PSSession` from the local server I will get the same error, unless I specify the `-EnableNetworkAccess` switch and then it will connect. This confuses me. Event viewer gives me Event ID 161 related to user authentication and error 142 for the session failing to create.

If I run `Test-WSMan` from the local server and a remote host it shows it running.

Here is the WinRM config and the listener config:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> winrm get winrm/config
Config
    MaxEnvelopeSizekb = 500
    MaxTimeoutms = 60000
    MaxBatchItems = 32000
    MaxProviderRequests = 4294967295
    Client
        NetworkDelayms = 5000
        URLPrefix = wsman
        AllowUnencrypted = false
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Digest = true
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = true
            CredSSP = false
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        TrustedHosts = 10.10.10.142
    Service
        RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)
        MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
        MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
        EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
        MaxConnections = 300
        MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
        AllowUnencrypted = false
        Auth
            Basic = false
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = false
            CredSSP = false
            CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        IPv4Filter = *
        IPv6Filter = *
        EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = false
        EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
        CertificateThumbprint
        AllowRemoteAccess = true
    Winrs
        AllowRemoteShellAccess = true
        IdleTimeout = 7200000
        MaxConcurrentUsers = 2147483647
        MaxShellRunTime = 2147483647
        MaxProcessesPerShell = 2147483647
        MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 2147483647
        MaxShellsPerUser = 2147483647

PS C:\Windows\system32> winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener
Listener
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTP
    Port = 5985
    Hostname
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint
    ListeningOn = 10.10.10.87, 127.0.0.1, ::1, fe80::4579:db85:c9cb:ead0%6
```

Other things I have tried:

- I have no GPO settings in place for WinRM.
- I have deleted and recreated the listener.
- I have reset the config of WinRM several times.
- Windows Advanced Firewall is disabled for Public, Private, and Domain
  networks.
- I have checked the `Set-PSSessionConfiguration -Name Microsoft.PowerShell -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI` permissions and the
  privileges seem okay.
- I have used IP addresses instead of hostnames with the same
  results.
- I have added my computer to the trusted host list and it does not
  work. This shouldn't be necessary though as the both the computers
  are on the same domain.
- Ran `Enable-PSRemoting -Force` (Although this should be unnecessary
  as WinRM is enabled by default for Server 2012 and forward).
- I have added my user to the Local Administrators and Remote
  Management Users on the server with no luck.
- I have adjusted the registry of `REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1` and this does not
  work regardless of its value.
- I have rebooted and ran an `sfc /scannow` as a last ditch effort.

Specs of the server, workstation, and my user:

- My domain account is a Domain Administrator.
- Server is Windows Server 2019 Standard.
- Workstation is Windows 10 Pro.
- PowerShell Version 5 for both.
- Both computers are on the same domain.
- Both computers are up to date.

I could use the local administrator account to poll this information and fix my intimidate problem, but that doesn't fix the underlying issue.

From the remote server there are no error entries in the Windows Remote Management Log, but on my computer I have these:

Error Event ID - 142

```
WSMan operation Enumeration failed, error code 2150858909
```

Error Event ID - 49

```
The WinRM protocol operation failed due to the following error: WinRM cannot process the request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090322 occurred while using Kerberos authentication: An unknown security error occurred.  
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config..
```

Error Event ID - 161

```
WinRM cannot process the request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090322 occurred while using Kerberos authentication: An unknown security error occurred.  
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config.
```

I can RDP into the server just fine, that's how I have been doing some of the local tests.

I tested these two commands:

`gwmi win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName Server1` executes normally with no issue, that's specifying the remote server and RDPing to running locally.

`Get-CimInstance win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName Server1` I cannot run from my workstation, but If I RDP into the sever and run it, it will execute normally.

The output of `SetSPN -X` returns no overlapping SPN's

The output of `SetSPN -L` returns:

```
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=Server1,OU=Servers,OU=Organization,DC=Organization,DC=LOCAL:
        TERMSRV/Server1.DOMAIN.LOCAL
        WSMAN/Server1.DOMAIN.LOCAL
        RestrictedKrbHost/Server1.DOMAIN.LOCAL
        HOST/Server1.DOMAIN.LOCAL
        TERMSRV/Server1
        WSMAN/Server1
        RestrictedKrbHost/Server1
        HOST/Server1
```

Any and all suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it resolved.

It was an SPN issue. The HTTP/Server1 and HTTP/Server1.domain were being used by a random user account named after the server.

After disabling the account and moving the SPN's to the computer object WinRM is now working like its supposed to.

[This](https://serverfault.com/questions/877459/remote-powershell-not-working-but-test-wsman-does) got me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue for myself with a reset of the spn

```
setspn -R <hostname>
```